# Checking if the following code is a compatible safe module

Tags: safe-core, safe

There are a few potential safe modules in [this repo](https://github.com/getwax/wax/tree/d47b94cd5ee2c6a5298d5fd1f54954c408654081/account-integrations/safe/src). Let's take an example of [SafeBlsPlugin.sol](https://github.com/getwax/wax/blob/d47b94cd5ee2c6a5298d5fd1f54954c408654081/account-integrations/safe/src/SafeBlsPlugin.sol).

From reading the [safe modules spec](https://github.com/5afe/safe-core-protocol-specs/blob/main/modules/README.md#plugins) it doesn't seem like the above module (and all other modules in that repo) follow any module spec properly.

Can someone check and confirm that none of these modules are safe compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module specs that you are referring to are taken from an initiative (the Safe Core Protocol) that is not currently being developed.

Modules should apply to standalone safes, and they do not require any specification to follow. Any safe is free to enable any contract as a module, as needed by their owners.

Hope it helps clarify the question. Best, Louis